# android class call other activity button

Tags: android, button

May I ask Quesion:

A.xml have button, but I want use b.class call a.xml button, source code :

```
 public Button getButton2() {

       Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return button2;
}
```

But when I running this app, button still didn't have any response, is have any wrong?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what did you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the context of the view to the new class. After that you can use this code, to run it in the UI thread.

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     // Button stuff here
                 }
             });
```

Comment: Yes, right. And you have to put the context of the MainActivity to the b.class

Comment: may I ask question: Is in the MainActivity put this source code? Because it's have error.
   public MainActivity(Context context) {
        
        this.ctx = context;
    }